# Why I got a wrong javascript message

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I've got a problem with my javascript/php page :
    I've done a java system alert when someone is connecting or registering on my website. I can connect my account correctly but there is the wrong message (I let you see my code)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#register_me').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var pseudonyme = $('#bean_name').val();
    var mail = $('#bean_email').val();
    var pswd = $('#bean_password').val();
    var repswd = $('#bean_repassword').val();
    if (pseudonyme === '' || pswd === '' || repswd === '' || mail === '') {
      swal("Oops :(", "Les champs doivent être remplis.", "error");
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        url: $this.attr('action'),
        type: $this.attr('method'),
        data: $this.serialize(),
        success: function(html) {
          if (html == "97736e1f6d89487783cb1b464745817b") {
            swal({
              title: "Création en cours...",
              text: "Vous pouvez à présent vous connectez.",
              type: "success",
              timer: 800,
              showConfirmButton: false
            });
            window.setTimeout(function() {
              window.location = "/moi";
            }, 1000);
          } else {
            swal("Oops :(", html, "error");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

now my register PHP form :

```
<form class="signup-form" id="register_me" action="<?= $site['lien']; ?>/app/actions/inscription.php" method="post" role="form" autocomplete="off">
  <h3 class="Ang-message">Inscris-toi dès maintenant sur <span><?= $site['nom']; ?></span>!</h3>
  <input type="text" name="bean_name" id="register__input" placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur" required>
  <input type="email" name="bean_email" id="register__input" placeholder="Adresse mail" required>
  <input type="password" name="bean_password" id="register__input" placeholder="Mot de passe" required>
  <input type="password" name="bean_repassword" id="register__input" placeholder="Confirmer votre mot de passe" required>

  <button type="submit" id="login__submit">Finaliser l'inscription</button>
  <a href="index" id="btn__register">Annuler</a>
</form>
```

I just give you a screenshot of what I see when I'm registered

[image: error (but I'm registered)]

Console:
[image: my console]

Network tab:
[image]

PHP script:

```
<?php
require('../../global.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    die('Une erreur est survenue.');
}

if(isset($_POST['bean_name'],$_POST['bean_email'],$_POST['bean_password'],$_POST['bean_repassword'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['bean_name']) AND !empty($_POST['bean_email']) AND !empty($_POST['bean_password']) AND !empty($_POST['bean_repassword'])) {
        $pseudo = htmlspecialchars($_POST['bean_name']);
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['bean_email']);
        $password = password_hash($_POST['bean_password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $pseudo_exist = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username');
        $pseudo_exist->execute([
                                   'username' => $pseudo
                                   ]);
        if($pseudo_exist->rowCount() == 0) {
            if(preg_match('`^([a-zA-Z0-9-=?!@:.,]{3,15})$`', $pseudo)) {
                $email_exist = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail = :mail');
                $email_exist->execute([
                                          'mail' => $email
                                          ]);
                if($email_exist->rowCount() == 0) {
                    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                        if($_POST['bean_password'] == $_POST['bean_repassword']) {
                            if(strlen($_POST['bean_password']) >= 6 AND strlen($_POST['bean_password']) >= 6) {
                                $insert_membre = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO users(username, password, mail, rank, credits, vip_points, activity_points, look, gender, motto, account_created, last_online, ip_reg) VALUES (:username, :password, :mail, :rank, :credits, :vip_points, :activity_points, :look, :gender, :motto, :account_created, :last_online, :ip_reg)');
                                $insert_membre->execute([
                                                            'username' => $pseudo,
                                                            'password' => $password,
                                                            'mail' => $email,
                                                            'rank' => "1",
                                                            'credits' => "1000000",
                                                            'vip_points' => "0",
                                                            'activity_points' => "1000000",
                                                            'look' => "hr-831-61.sh-290-62.ch-3208-110-92.hd-180-2.lg-275-62",
                                                            'gender' => "M",
                                                            'motto' => "Je suis nouveau !",
                                                            'account_created' => time(),
                                                            'last_online' => time(),
                                                            'ip_reg' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
                                                            ]);
                                $_SESSION['id'] = $bdd->lastInsertId();
                                echo '97736e1f6d89487783cb1b464745817b';
                            } else {
                                echo 'Le mot de passe doit contenir plus de 6 caractÃ¨res.';
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo 'Les mots de passe ne correspondent pas.';
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo 'L\'adresse e-mail n\'est pas valide.';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'Cette adresse e-mail est dÃ©jÃ  utilisÃ©e.';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'Ton pseudo contient des caractÃ¨res non-autorisÃ©s.';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Ce pseudo est dÃ©jÃ  utilisÃ©.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Merci de remplir tous les champs.';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try using `html.trim()`, there might be extra whitespace around the string that the PHP script echoes.

Comment: If that doesn't solve it, go to the Network tab while you send the AJAX request, and look at the response to make sure there isn't something extra.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I let u check my console : https://image.ibb.co/gx1PVK/3a7190b525956324220d5a1f9cfbd3ea.png

Comment: That's not the Network tab. Go to the network tab, make your AJAX request, click on the `inscript.php` URL, click on `Response` to see the response.

Comment: I did it, that's what I see : preview.ibb.co/c3PpVK/sans_titre.png

Comment: Do you see the red dot before the number? You need to figure out why the PHP script is sending that and fix it.

Comment: Yes I know where is the problem, but how to solve it? My inscription.php file here : https://image.ibb.co/hTxHkK/aaaaa.png and https://image.ibb.co/jmaCkK/bbbbbbb.png but when the code "97736e1f6d89487783cb1b464745817b" is generate this have to be appear : https://image.ibb.co/hXEoQK/cccccc.png (and the redirection after)

Comment: Add the PHP code to the question. Post it as formatted text, not an image.

Comment: My guess is there's a BOM character at the beginning of the PHP file.

Comment: I can't post it when I edit, I have uploaded the inscription.php : https://files.fm/u/q7zsqs3y

Comment: I had no problem posting it, I added it to the question for you. When you post code, use the `{}` tool in the SO editor to mark it as code so it will be formatted correctly.

Comment: There's nothing in the script that I can see that's causing this problem. Maybe it's in `global.php`?

Comment: My global.php just regroup this : <?php
require_once('app/config.php');
require_once('app/sessions.php');
require_once('app/system.php');
?>

Comment: Maybe one of those scripts has it. The character has to be coming from somewhere.